# cellspace, tabularx and siunitx: column specifier "CX" doesn't work

Tags: tabularx, siunitx, cellspace

please, consider the following two mwe-s:

the first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{3cm}{X Cc c}
    \hline
A   &   123   &   456   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

the second:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{3cm}{CX c c}
    \hline
A   &   123   &   456   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

the first one work as expected, the second one throw error:

```
! Package array error: Illegal pream-token (\ecolumn): `c' used.
```

apparently specifier `CX` doesn't work as i expected. what i doing wrong?

Comment: For me (TL 2016), it works if I write `C{X}` instead of `X` in the `\begin{tabularx}{3cm}{...}` spec.

Comment: @frougon, indeed. so far this i dindn't found in mentioned packages documentation :-(

Comment: I don't find it obvious from the documentation either (where explicit specifiers with braces like `p{3cm}` are given where `S{...}` is mentioned), that's why I just said “it works for me” and didn't propose it as an answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like all column specifiers  that set the column width (`p`, `m`, `b`), the `X` column type requires a pair of braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{25pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{25pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{3cm}{C{X} c c}
    \hline
A & 123 & 456 \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:
 @UlrikeFischer's answer reminded me `cellspace` now lets you change the pre-specifier via an option of the package, so you're no more dependent on `siunitx` patch: if  the part of siunitx concerning cellspace is removed, using, say:

```
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
```

you can use `{OX c c}`as a preamble for the table, without braces around `X` (tested).

Comment: now i wonder, why specifier `SX` works if i delete `siunitx` package. for this reason i mentioned it in question title. however, for all columns' specifiers whit prescribed column width, encapsulation into curly braces is necessary.

Comment: @Zarko: That's strange… A few years ago, neither would work without braces, if I remember well, and I didn't have the opportunity to test it recently. Maybe  it (partially) works without braces since last year update?

Comment: hm, this doesn't work at me -(. error: `! File ended while scaning use of \__siunitx_tmp:w }.` i have installed recent `siunitx` and with tables related packages

Comment: And did you update cellspace?

Comment: i have: `cellspace 2017/08/12—v1.7`, siunitx  v2.7o,  2018-05-02. it seems that Ulrike has right: it is also necessary to fool `siunitx`.

Comment: @Zarko: That's right. I had tested with the `O` pre-specifier  after I had commented the part of SIunitx concerning `cellspace`.

Answer (score 7):

The code siunitx uses to change the cellspace column type from S to C seems to be faulty. If one let cellspace change the name and fool siunitx so that it doesn't interfere it works again:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[column=C]{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\cslet{ver@cellspace.sty}{\somethingundefined} %fool siunitx 
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{3cm}{CX c c}
    \hline
A   &   123   &   456   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```