# Vertical space between table rows

Tags: tabularx

I'm trying to increase the space between the rows of the `tabularx` table. The following code works fine and does what I want:

```
\begin{tabularx}{5ex}{X}
    text \\[2ex]
    x
\end{tabularx}
```

However, if the text is too long and does not fit into one line, then the vertical space does not work:

```
\begin{tabularx}{5ex}{X}
    text text \\[2ex]
    x
\end{tabularx}
```

Please tell me how I can fix the code so that it works. The variant to use `(N - 1) * \baselineskip + 2ex` is not suitable, since it depends on the number of lines of text `N`.

**UPD** full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    % code above
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always post full but minimal examples others can just copy and test as is. Then you are much more likely to get help.

Comment: Your approach is not the best. Better is to use tables, where you can set distance between rows as at `tabularray`  or use package by which you can se vertical spaces in cells, as is `cellspace`. For the last see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431076

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tabularx` and `cellspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}% better, than {} aren't necessary
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2ex}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2ex}
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\usepackage{tabularx}               % "tabularx" had to be after "cellspace"

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{5ex}{OX}
\hline
    text text   \\ 
\hline
    x           \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

`hline`s are added for better visibility of vertical distances)

[image]

With `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}  

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{width=5ex,
             hlines, % for better visibility of vertical distances
             colspec = {X},
             rowsep=2ex}
    text text   \\ 
    x           \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

**Addendum:**
Apparently question is not clear at all. From comment below follows, that only between some rows is desired to increase distance between rows. The simplest way top do this is use of the `\addlinespace[<desired space>]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}   
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{5ex}{X}
    text text   \\
    text text   \\
    \addlinespace[2ex] % you can omit this space, if its default value 3pt is ok
        x           \\
    text text   \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not mean setting an increased indentation between all the rows of the table, but only between some of them. Unfortunately, the solutions you have proposed do not suit me. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @AlexeyIsmagilov, than please make your question more clear. See addendum to answer.

Comment: it seemed to me that I had formulated the question well and that it would be clear that I meant the interval between only some lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `arraystretch` to stretch cells by a factor `<F>`:

```
\renewcommand\arraystretch{<F>}
```

with 1.0 being default. The effect is asymmetric but small factors work fine.

On top of `arraystretch`, it is also possible to insert and append invisible elements before and after the cell content, such as zero-length vertical bars of height and depth greater than the a single line of text. The bars cause cells to adapt to such content and you gain an effect of increased space.

This can be automated at column definition. If the effect needs to be cancelled or changed at a specific row, use `\multicolumn` with altered settings.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand\upstrut[1][2ex]{\rule[1.5ex]{0pt}{#1}}
\newcommand\lostrut[1][2ex]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{9ex}{>{\upstrut}X<{\lostrut}}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{head}} \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{l<{\lostrut[4ex]}}{x} \\
  text text \\
  text text \\
  text text \\
  \multicolumn{1}{>{\upstrut[4ex]}l}{x} \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT. However, as in [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/679701/31283)'s answer, you can simplify things by employing `tabularray`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    width = 9ex,
    colspec = {X},
    hline{1-2,Z},
    row{3-Y} = {rowsep=2ex},
  }
  \textbf{head} \\
  x \\
  text text \\
  text text \\
  text text \\
  x \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]